# How to repair straight cut floor joist?

Tags: repair, floor, joists

What's the best way to repair a cut floor joist? It looks like when removing floor boards for remodel, someone has cut about half way through the top of joist with saw straight cut. No notching. I'm thinking of either metal plate and coach bolting with a 30 inch over hang of cut or adding new wood either side as with the plate. Would this be the right method ?

Comment: I think the only "approved" method, is to contact an Engineer and have them craft a plan for you.

Comment: Or you could just sister it for its entire length, starting at the supported end on each side. Basically replace it without removing it.

Comment: In my opinion, both of the above comments are correct. However, there might be alternatives if you can describe in more detail the situation. How big is the joist? Describe the load/spacing of the rest of the joists. Where in the span is the kerf? How deep is the kerf? If there are bearing walls below, where are they relative to the cut?

Comment: Further to @AloysiusDefenestrate's comment, if you think it would be helpful, you could include a photo or sketch.